# zip command is failing during high memory usage

Tags: rhel, perl, zip

We have several perl scripts, which generates and emails reports. The script that emails the files expects a `.zip` extension. The report scripts generates a `.txt` or `.xls` file and then runs the following `zip` command:

```
print `zip -m $zip_filename $output_filename`;
```

What's happening is that in some cases (typically, when the perl script uses a lot of memory), the above command fails. From what I gathered the script fails, because there is not enough memory to run the `zip` command. This is a sporadic problem, and a bit hard to pin-down.

I have to generate `.zip` files and cannot use a different compression method.

I was hoping that someone could tell me whats going on here. I am suspecting that the `-m` flag might be causing this.

What's weird to me is that I have manually ran the `zip` command from `bash` several times, and never had it fail, even while using a lot of memory.

Here's the result of a `free` command to give you an idea of how much memory I am talking about. The report scripts can occasionally use more than 10GB of Memory:

```
-bash-4.1$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      49409336   48948192     461144          0    1184716    8147564
-/+ buffers/cache:   39615912    9793424
Swap:      2047992    2047988          4
```

`$output_filename` could be a pattern matching more than one file.

Comment: Can't promise it will solve the problem, but using [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip) will at least spare the fork/exec overhead implicit in backticks.

Comment: Can you add more swap space?

Comment: Check the limits of the user running the script, e.g. `ulimit -a`. Scripts started from cron might have different limits, so add this ulimit call to your application.

Comment: Thanks. I can't really add more swap space. all the relevant fields in ulimit -a seem to be unlimited. I am testing out Archive::Zip.

Comment: Did it help? Please give feedback :)!

Comment: Not sure yet honestly, still testing.

Comment: “From what I gathered the script fails” — what did you gather? How do you know that it's related to the call to `zip`? What is `$?` after the call (and do you check it?)?